# Connecting sparkly to HDP-Sandbox Spark instance

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr, livy, hdp

I would like to connect R instance to Spark running on HDP-Sandbox deployed on Docker on one local machine. The error message indicates that `--version` call on `spark-submit` fails.

## R instance

```
packageVersion("sparklyr")
# [1] ‘1.0.1’

# Set old JAVA version
Sys.setenv("JAVA_HOME" =
               "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home")

library(sparklyr)

sc <- spark_connect(
    master = " http://localhost:4040",
    spark_home = "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client",
    app_name = "RStudio",
    method = "shell"
)
```

> Error in `system2(file.path(spark_home, "bin", "spark-submit"),
>   "--version",`  :    error in running command

## HDP

```
[root@sandbox-hdp ~]# /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/bin/spark-submit --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.1.3.0.1.0-187
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_191
Branch HEAD
Compiled by user jenkins on 2018-09-19T10:10:07Z
Revision fe7bed1ca174a6687ebd2aa0f8ba5fb7bf668399
Url git@github.com:hortonworks/spark2.git
Type --help for more information.
```

## *Update*

I've resorted to using Livy as it seems to be an easier solution. I have opened `8999` port that is referenced in the `livy.conf` file and can now access Livy UI at `http://localhost:8999/ui`.

[image: Livy Session]

Despite this, I still keep getting errors when trying to connect:

```
config <- livy_config()
sc <- spark_connect(master = "http://localhost:8999",
                     method = "livy",
                     config = config)
# Error in livy_connection(master = master, config = config, app_name, version,  : 
# Failed to launch livy session, session status is still starting after waiting for 60 seconds


config <- livy_config(username = "root", password = "***")
sc <- spark_connect(master = "http://localhost:8999",
                     method = "livy",
                     config = config)
# Error in livy_connection(master = master, config = config, app_name, version,  : 
# Failed to launch livy session, session status is still starting after waiting for 60 seconds
```